# How to pass a Set of Id's to a visualforce page having a custom controller from an apex class?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Pass a Set of Id's to a visualforce page having a custom controller from an apex class.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="myVFPageController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
<!-- Apex Page Block Table to display the Records for accLst -->
</apex:page>
```

Custom Controller

```
public class myVFPageController {

public Set<String>   recIds {get; set;}
public List<Account> accLst {get; set;}

public myVFPageController () {
    //Based on the incoming recIds, query the records and update accLst
    }
}
```

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class call_Page {
@future
public static void call_Page(Set<Id> recIds) {
    PageReference page = Page.myVFPage;
    //Pass the record Ids to  visualforce page
    page.getParameters().put();//This will not work as its a Map of String, String
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you post the code that you have tried and the issue you are facing with that ?

Comment: @VijayGanji I have updated the code, I am not unable to figure out the approach to pass the Set of Ids to visualforce page controller.

Comment: Why do you need two controllers ? Can you not use the same controller for `PDF` page as well ? Do you have any specific reason for using different controller for `PDF` page ?

Comment: call_Page is a future method, so I have created a seperate controller for the visualforce page.

Comment: General approach = convert your set of IDs into a CSV string of IDs and put this into a single query parameter on the generated page URL (reference) then write your VF page controller to get this single query parameter and parse the CSV back into a set/list of IDs (can use String.split for this parsing).

Comment: @PhilW , Suggested solution resolved the issue. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General approach is to convert your set of IDs into a CSV string of IDs and put this into a single query parameter on the generated page URL (reference) then write your VF page controller to get this single query parameter and parse the CSV back into a set/list of IDs (can use String.split for this parsing).